# Visual Studios Remote Build Fails Error Code 2

Tags: visual-studio-cordova, taco

Trying to output IPA File, and each attempt I'm getting this.

I have created the xcode8.js, setup the Config with the Before_Compile. But it still says Command Not Found.

Why? Any Help.

```
Executing script found in hooks directory for hook "before_compile": hooks/before_compile/xcode8.js
Running command: /Users/rblake/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3584/cordovaApp/hooks/before_compile/xcode8.js /Users/rblake/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3584/cordovaApp
/Users/rblake/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3584/cordovaApp/hooks/before_compile/xcode8.js: line 1: use strict: command not found
/Users/rblake/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3584/cordovaApp/hooks/before_compile/xcode8.js: line 1: 
: command not found
/Users/rblake/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3584/cordovaApp/hooks/before_compile/xcode8.js: line 2: 
: command not found
/Users/rblake/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3584/cordovaApp/hooks/before_compile/xcode8.js: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/Users/rblake/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3584/cordovaApp/hooks/before_compile/xcode8.js: line 3: `var fs    = require('fs');
```

Comment: Error  Remote build error from the build server http://192.168.0.81:3000/cordova - Build failed with error Hook failed with error code 2: /Users/rblake/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3584/cordovaApp/hooks/before_compile/xcode8.js